# ¿Cómo añadir etiqueta de datos a un gráfico de barras en ggplot2?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

He generado un gráfico de barras usando `ggplot2` y `geom_bar` a partir del número de casos detectados por la columna subcategoría, que es un tipo de dato `char`, por ello uso `as.factor()`.

La cuestión es que me gustaría añadir en la parte superior de cada columna el valor de la misma, he probado a usar `geom_text()` de varias formas posibles, pero me da error:

```
# 3 Gráfica de solicitudes por subcategoría
ggplot(data = datos) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = subcategoria, fill = as.factor(subcategoria))) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = subcategoria)) +
  ylab("Formularios") + 
  xlab("Subcategoria") + 
  ggtitle("Solicitudes por Subcategoria") + 
  labs(fill = "Subcategorías") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Error

> Error in ggplot(data = datos) : could not find function "ggplot"

Si no uso `geom_text()` la gráfica se muestra sin problemas, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar un `geom_text()` necesitas establecer dos dimensiones estéticas, `x` y `label`. en tu ejemplo solo configuraste `x`, además entiendo que lo que buscas es mostrar el valor numérico de cada barra, por lo que te sugiero hacer esto:

```
geom_text(stat='count', aes(x = subcategoria, label = ..count..), vjust = -1)
```

El `x` es las `subcategoria` y la etiqueta será la cantidad `label = ..count..`. Con `vjust = -1` ajustamos mejor la posición de cada etiqueta con respecto a las barras

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado a la perfección.